# problems in finding the masterpage inside ACSX control

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASCX control and I want to find the masterfind that holds it.
( i do not have this.Master, since its a control)

how can I access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `Control` has a reference on it's `Page` via [Control.Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.page.aspx) property and as you already know `Page` references it's `MasterPage` via [Page.Master](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.master.aspx).

C#

```
MyMasterType myMaster = (MyMasterType)this.Page.Master;
```

VB.NET

```
Dim myMaster as MyMasterType = DirectCast(Me.Page.Master, MyMasterType)
```

`MyMasterType` is the actual type of your masterpage.

Here are some informations on communication between `Page` and `UserControls`:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/user-controls/Page_UserControl.aspx